# php mail attachments weird behaviour

Tags: php, smtp, email, attachment

I need some help here with a really weird situation.. i made a webmail form to send emails with multiple attachments, it worked out of the box yesterday but today it only sends 1 file as an attachment and not multiple. O_O

I revert my SVN to an older revision also and the problem still persists, any idea? this is really weird.. how working stuff brake from one day to another, i think the problem must be the SMTP server or something. Help please!

Code:

```
        $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";


            $attachments = TRUE;
        $body = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
        "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
        $body . "\n\n";
        $body .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $attach = array();
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']);$i++)
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $type = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
            $name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
            $size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];

            if (file_exists($tmp_name)){
                $kb = $size/1024;
                $kbSize = round($kb*100)/100;

                if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){
                    $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
                    $fdata = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name)); //stream file to var and send it in headers
                    fclose($file);
                    $fdata = chunk_split(base64_encode($fdata));
                    $body .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" . 
                        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" . 
                        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $fdata . "\n\n";
                    $body .= "--{$mime_boundary}-\n";
                }
            }       
        }
        $sent = myMailer::sendAttached($from,$to,$subject,$body,$mime_boundary,$multi);
```

MyMailer class, sendAttached Method:

```
    public static function sendAttached($from,$to,$subject,$body,$mime,$multi=FALSE)
{

    $headers = 'From: Website <'.$from.'>'. "\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from. "\r\n".
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
    " boundary=\"{$mime}\"";

    if($multi == TRUE && is_array($to)){
        foreach($to as $item)
        {
            mail(trim($item),$subject,$body,$headers);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: `cat your_code | stackoverflow --question > answers`... In other words... post your code :-)

Comment: there u are :) .. the code is not the problem, as i said.. it was working and i revert to revision in svn and still sending 1 and not 3 attachments as it used to send

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps at some point move theo following outside the `for` loop:

```
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
```

Ive never tried to create a complex multipart message from scratch like this (i always use an existing library like Swift Mailer or Zend_Mail), but doesnt each file have to be its own part and thus have its own boundries?